# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<FriendsProvider> above this friendsPage Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is my provider:

```
class FriendsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  FriendsProvider() {
    loadCountries().then((countries) {
      _countries = countries;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  List<MyUser> _countries = [];

  List<MyUser> get countries => _countries;

  Future loadCountries() async {
    final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/country_codes.json');
    final countriesJson = json.decode(data);

    return countriesJson.keys.map<MyUser>((code) {
      final json = countriesJson[code];
      final newJson = json..addAll({'code': code.toLowerCase()});

      return MyUser.fromJson(newJson);
    }).toList()
      ..sort(Utils.ascendingSort);
  }
}
```

And in the build method of another class I call it in this way

```
final provider = Provider.of<FriendsProvider>(context);
```

but I get the error in the title. What is wrong and how can I fix?

Comment: Did you create the provider as a top level widget?

Comment: @PeterHaddad What is a top level widget and how can I create one?

Comment: Where did you put the provider?

Comment: @h8moss in another dart file in the same folder of the class in which I use it

Comment: I meant on your widget tree, for `provider.of` to work, you need to place a provider widget somewhere in your tree. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

In Your **`main.dart`** file  Check You Register this Provider or not.

You have add your "FriendsProvider" provider.